# Indexing XML document in Solr

Tags: solr

XML file is not getting indexed in Solr. For field Org in xml file we have an attribute id. data-config.xml is
:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="FileDataSource" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <document>
<entity name="OrgDBdir" rootEntity="false" dataSource="null"
        processor="FileListEntityProcessor"
                fileName="orgdb.xml" recursive="true"
                        baseDir="/var/www/html/intranet"
                                >
    <entity name="OrgDB"
        processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
        stream="true"
        useSolrAddSchema="true"
        pk="id"
        datasource="OrgDBdir"
        forEach="/Orgs/Org"
        url="${OrgDBdir.fileAbsolutePath}"
        transformer="DateFormatTransformer, RegexTransformer">
        <field column="id" xpath="/Orgs/Org/[@id]"/>
        <filed column="orgname"  xpath="/Orgs/Org/OrgName"/>
        <filed column="officialname"  xpath="/Orgs/Org/OfficialName"/>
    </entity>
    </entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```